# Using already translated words in ngx-translate

Tags: angular, ngx-translate

I`m new to ngx-translate and need to reuse already translated words in other sentences. I´ve already implemented a running solution but I am not sure if there is a better way.

My en.json looks like:

```
{
    "GLOBAL": {
       "gateway": "Gateway"
       "test": The {{gateway}} ist configured
    }
}
```

In the HTML code im using parameters to get used of the translation for Gateway. Which looks like this:

```
<p>{{'GLOBAL.test' | translate:{'gateway': ('GLOBAL.gateway' | translate)}}</p>
```

This is working as excpected. Im wonder if there isn't a better solution to reuse words.

Thanks in regard.

Comment: Nope. Unfortunately this is the way to go. You can build yourself a wrapper-method around it that you call, or build a new directive. But in general, this needs to be the output in the end.